# ordinary differential equations?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm doing some work on ODEs and I am unable to prove that the solutions that are given are the solutions to the given ODE.

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you

Comment: What are your thoughts? At least compute $dy/dx$ and plug it into the ODE together with the function itself. You may or may not then have problems showing that the two sides are equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: There is nothing to hint regarding @Henning comment about the first part. For the second part try to use [Picard–Lindelöf theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem). Focus on $f(x,y)=3y^{2/3}$ and probe the cases where the OE has no solution and the cases the solution is unique.

Comment: That theorem to the rescue, again! +1

Comment: I've tried reading this theorem but I don't understand it. Could someone help me out and explain to me how this ties in with the question? that would be great thanks :)